# How to filter features from CountVectorizer?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, topic-modeling, data-cleaning, data-science

I am doing a text analysis (topic modeling) and when I run it through `CountVectorizer`, I get a bunch of numbers, dates, and locations that are quite irrelevant to my needs. I thought I would be feeding in the [preprocessing function](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.build_preprocessor), but the [scikit-learn page for preprocessing](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html) doesn't seem to have any information I need in building the preprocessor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change `token_pattern` parameter in `CountVectorizer`.

Token pattern is regular expression denoting what constitutes a “token”, only used if `analyzer == 'word'`.  Type of token patter is string.

Default `token_pattern=r"(?u)\b\w\w+\b"`. The default regexp select tokens of 2 or more alphanumeric characters (punctuation is completely ignored and always treated as a token separator). You can change it to meet your needs(for example ignore dates).